# why and when we use object destructuring in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I've seen a lot of code like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
       ({coords}) => {
         const {latitude, longitude} = coords
         this.setState({
           position: {
             latitude,
             longitude,
           },
           region: {
             latitude,
             longitude,
             latitudeDelta: 0.005,
             longitudeDelta: 0.001,
           }
         })
       },
       (error) => alert('Error: Are location services on?'),
       {enableHighAccuracy: true}
     );
```

My question is why and when we use object destructuring in parameter.

Why `coords` using object destructuring while `error` not using it?

Comment: because `({coords})` destructures, `(error)` does not ... use `{}` to destructure the incoming argument, don't use `{}` to get the whole argument - perhaps I've misunderstood your question, you seem to know what `{}` does, you want to know why you'd do it? because you're only interested in the `coords` property of the argument and nothing else in the object that is passed in the argument

Answer (score 3):

This is all about objects in JS. I suggest you read more on objects.

But here is a simple example.

```
const car = {door: "blue", tires: 4}.
```

Of course, you can use it like `car.door` to get `blue`, or `car.tires` to get `4`. But you can see you are writing the same code `car.` everywhere. It would be better just to do the following:

```
const {door, tires} = car
```

Then everywhere else, you can simply do `door` and `tires`. It is all about personal preference. I use it because it is simple and easy to see, and less duplicate code. No good or bad.

As far as your why `error` does not need to destructur is because we are simply checking if `error` exists. This is the same as what you wrote:

```
(error) => alert('something')
```

and

```
(Boolean(error)) => alert('something').
```

Here you do not even care what is inside of `error`, all you want to know if there is an `error` or not. That's why you do not need to destructure.

If you want to get some item inside the `error`, let's say `code` is one of the keys of `error`. Then you can do

```
({code}) => alert(code)
```

Comment: It seems usable (makes code shorter) in the 2-field example above. But I often see people use it with just even one field. E.g. `const { door } = car`. Why doing this? What's wrong with `const door = car.door`? Or with just using `car.door` in the code? (in many cases writing `car.door` is actually better because often there's some `house.door` and 'namespacing' door with its owner object makes code more readable in many cases. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @WannaKnowAll you are correct, this is totally personal preference. If you have only one field you need, yes then there is no point, but often time you need 3 or 4 together. Then it is a lot more concise to use destruction.